# Stumped on function involving click and addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

After many a headache, I am still wrestling with this function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var items = $(".tabs-group .sidebar ul li:not(:last-child) a");
    var home = $(".tabs-group .sidebar ul li:last-child a");

    $("home").click( function () {
        $("items").addClass("pulse");
    $("items").click( function () {
       $("items").removeClass("pulse");
    });
});
```

Basically it adds class "pulse" to "items" when "home" is clicked, and removes "pulse" from "items" when "items" is clicked.

Is the syntax correct? I am using jsFiddle to work with it. I don't have a program to check for errors, what is a good quick one to use?

Here is the jsfiddle with the function: http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/KjcnL/

Comment: *I don't have a program to check for errors.* It is called the browser's console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but your syntax is wrong: Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var items = $(".tabs-group .sidebar ul li:not(:last-child) a");
    var home = $(".tabs-group .sidebar ul li:last-child a");

    home.click( function () {
        $(this).addClass("pulse");
    });
    items.click( function () {
       $(this).removeClass("pulse");
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a little explanation, the `$()` function returns a jQuery object. so by doing `var items = $("...");` you are creating a jQuery object that you then can use later on - the html elements selected in the initial function call are all preserved in the jQuery object.